# Woocommerce Quantity Dropdown Selector Fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing an online store with WooCommerce. I have managed to display a quantity selector using this code in the functions file:

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data = null) {

  global $product;
  if (!$data) {
    $defaults = array(
      'input_name' => 'quantity',
      'input_value' => '1',
      'max_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
      'min_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
      'step' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
      'style' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product )
    );
  } else {
    $defaults = array(
      'input_name' => $data['input_name'],
      'input_value' => $data['input_value'],
      'max_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
      'min_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
      'step' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
      'style' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product )
    );
  }

  if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
    $min = $defaults['min_value'];
  else $min = 1;

  foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $key) { 
    if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
      $max = $key['max_qty'];
    else $max = $key['max_qty'];
  }

  if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
    $step = $defaults['step'];
  else $step = 1;
  $options = '';

  for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
    $selected = $count === $defaults['input_value'] ? ' selected' : '';
    $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '"'.$selected.'>' . $count . '</option>';
  }

  echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
}
```

It works perfect under the single product pages, but the problem comes on the cart page, giving this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_available_variations() on a non-object in functions.php on line 240 -> foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $key) {

Does anyone know how could I fix this?

Single product: http://www.ticketexpress.com.au/product/hong-kong-sevens-friday-tickets/

Cart page: http://www.ticketexpress.com.au/cart/

Comment: What calls this function? It shouldn't be called the way it is on the cart page...

Comment: i don't know its just being called

Comment: @Inigo find who calls `woocommerce_quantity_input` or look for something that has something like `add_action('*some hook here*', 'woocommerce_quantity_input');`

Comment: @Reigel I can find that in many places, what should I do with it?

Comment: let us see what is it... by the way, that should be the one in your functions.php that we want to see... because calling `global $product;` is wrong here... we will know that when we know who's calling this function...

Comment: you will not have `global $product;` on cart page. it will be null, I think..

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're overriding a woocommerce function. I won't suggest doing what your doing especially on a plugin. It's dangerous. Other plugins might be using that function. There's a filter you can use to changed the args. And there's a woocommerce template for quantity input you can copy to your theme and do your edits. This should be the safest and the right way of doing it.

if you need to change the `$default` or the given `$args` use `woocommerce_quantity_input_args` filter...

something like this... copy this to your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args','my_quantity_input_args',10,2);
function my_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){

    // add style to the $default;
    $args['style'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product );

    // check for min
    if ( empty( $args['min_value'] ) )
        $args['min_value'] = 1;

    // check for max
    if ( empty( $args['max_value'] ) )
        $args['max_value'] = 8; // I'm not sure where to get your max_qty.

    return $args;
}
```

then locate `quantity-input.php` file in your plugins folder, `woocommerce/templates/global/quantity-input.php`. Copy it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php`

Do your edits. Remove the codes there and replace it with the code below.. These next lines of codes will give you exactly what you are trying to do now.

```
  for ( $count = $min_value; $count <= $max_value; $count = $count+$step ) {
    $selected = $count === $input_value ? ' selected' : '';
    $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '"'.$selected.'>' . $count . '</option>';
  }

  echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $style . '" ><select name="' . esc_attr( $input_name ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Reigel. Unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: why the down vote? if there's a problem about my answer, you can leave a comment... down voting it will not do anything to correct what is wrong..